# Redirecting to a Lightning Component from Apex Class not working in Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, customer-community, partner-communities

I have a Lightning Component which implements 'isURLAddressable' interface. I am calling this component from my Apex Class.

ApexClass

```
...
'/lightning/cmp/c__TestComp?c__param1=test';
...
```

Within Salesforce, this URL works fine and I get navigated to my TestComp component. But in Communities,it is not working.

I tried modifying the URL to below:

```
...
'/<CommunityURL>/lightning/cmp/c__TestComp?c__param1=test' ---- Not Working in Communities

OR

'/<CommunityURL>/cmp/c__TestComp?c__param1=test' ---- Not Working in Communities

...
```

Any idea on how can I call Lightning Component from Apex class which could work in Communities?

Answer (score 0):

I think this interface is not available in community.

> This navigation feature is supported only in Lightning Experience and
>   the Salesforce App.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation

Comment: But even If I remove 'isURLAddressable' interface from the component, still it doesn't gets called. Looks like there is some other way to call the Component in the URL for communitites.

Comment: You can not call a component which is on different page. Simple solution would be create a new page in community, drag your lightning component there and provide url of that page in your code

Comment: Can you help me with a small code snippet?

Comment: You need to redirect to a url, which is a lightning component,  from apex, right?

Comment: Yes right.. In Salesforce the URL '/lightning/cmp/c__TestComp?c__param1=test';  works fine but in Communities it is not working even if I prefix CommunityURL '/<CommunityURL>/lightning/cmp/c__TestComp?c__param1=test'

Comment: As I said, it would not work in community. In community create a page, let's say 'testpage' and drag your lightning component there using community builder. Now, you can use this page link like '/<CommunityURL>/testpage?c__param1=test'. However, you will have to read the parameter using javascript or design attributes...